# Assign Port to specific user

Tags: port, user, debian-lenny

I need to be able to assign specific ports to a given user to listen at. Say I have user X, I want him to be able to only listen on port 500. User Y only on port 501. How can I do this? Im working on a debian lenny.

Edit: User X and Y should not be able to touch any other port, not assigned to them, within a given range. (like port 100-1000)

Comment: I think you need to provide a lot more background information here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non root users cannot listen (or even open) ports below 1024.

To restrict users to other single ports above 1024, you can use the  --uid-owner option of iptables.
See "man iptables".

If you dont want to mess with iptables yourself (but still have a decent knowledge of networking/firewalling), my personal favourite firewalling solution is firehol. It has user/uid
commands to help you set up per-user restrictions.

http://firehol.sourceforge.net/

Comment: sorry about the confusion about the ports below 1024. I just picked a bad range. Anyway, I cant assign them a range with iptables/firehol?